# Update: Add more control: hide header on scroll and work from a certain width size

Tags: javascript, html, css, scroll

**Updated this question again:**

I have an existing script which works, but the only thing that I would like to have more control on is specifying the tolerance for up/down scroll and when it shows or hides the menu. Currently, the menu slides up at first after scrolling `44px` (delta value)--which is OK--but after that, I would like the menu to scroll up or down directly on scroll. When you set the delta value to `0px` you can see what i mean, but than it doesn't have the delay at the first scroll (understand it?).

Second thing is that i would like to add a function to the script that will let me control from which width it will start to work. I want it to work from 667px and downwards and not work when it is more than that value (some what like a media query).

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/7vtmbgkx/10/)

```
// Hide header on scroll down //

var didScroll;
var lastScrollTop = 0;
var delta = 44;
var navbarHeight = $('header').outerHeight();

$(window).scroll(function(event){
didScroll = true;
});

setInterval(function() {
if (didScroll) {
    hasScrolled();
    didScroll = false;
}
}, 250);

function hasScrolled() {
var st = $(this).scrollTop();

// Make sure they scroll more than delta
if(Math.abs(lastScrollTop - st) <= delta)
    return;

// If they scrolled down and are past the navbar, add class .nav-up.
// This is necessary so you never see what is "behind" the navbar.
if (st > lastScrollTop && st > navbarHeight){
    // Scroll Down
    $('header').addClass('nav-up');
} else {
    // Scroll Up
    if(st + $(window).height() < $(document).height()) {
        $('header').removeClass('nav-up');
    }
}

lastScrollTop = st;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Two questions / two answers:

but after that I would like the menu to scroll up or down directly on scroll

1. set delta to 0

Also what is the 250 value? Can't seem to see what it does?

2. 250 is the interval of the check if the user scrolled

Comment: Thanks Jasper! I know it is just a small difference, but i set the delta to  a value of '44px' so the menu (44px in height) doesn't slide up directly with the first scroll and after that i would like it to react as it does when the value is set to '0px'. Is that possible?

Comment: The problem could be this. As you asked; 250 is the interval (in miliseconds) of the check if scrolled. You can lower the interval. I strongly advice against this, it will impact your page performance

Comment: So not adjusting the interval OK, but adding a second value after the first scroll of 44px isn't possible? Or adding script that says after 44px set delta to 0?

Comment: Anyone can help me must be easy to this